# Play framework sometimes needs getters and setters, sometimes it does not

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, web-deployment

I started a simple webapp based on play. After a bit of refactoring the login-form stopped working. I used an entity-bean with simple public fields. I moved it from one controller to another while refactoring and of cause corrected the references. It always told me I'm an invalid user.

During debugging I've found that the fields aren't set anymore. However, what really confused me: I manually added getters and setters to the public fields and suddenly it worked again. I've done now quite a bit of research why it works in the default-controller called "Application" but not in my own one called "Registration".

There isn't much code involved, here a few points:

```
public class RegistrationLogin extends Controller {

    public static class Login {
        @Required
        public String email;
        @Required
        public String password;
        public String validate() {

/* here is the interesting part, when I call "form.hasErrors" in 
authenticateLogin and this validate-method gets called, email and 
password both are null. If I create getters and setters they are set correctly */

            if (User.authenticate(email, password) == null) {
                return "Invalid user or password";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

public static Result authenticateLogin() {
    Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest("email", "password");
    String title = "Login";
    if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(login.render(title,loginForm));
    } else {
        session().clear();
        session("email", loginForm.get().email);
        return redirect(
                routes.Application.show(Ebean.find(User.class).where().ieq("email",loginForm.get().email).findUnique().getName())
        );
    }
}
```

When I had Login defined in Application (the default-controller which is generated when you start a project) it worked with just the fields.

Whats the origin of this behavior? Any hint might be helpful.

Comment: Could you show us some code? With this little information I am afraid we will not be able to help much...

Comment: I just added a bit of code. Hope this helps :)